# Tablas con PK són más rápidas en responder consultas, por qué?

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una tabla con 15 columnas, 2 llaves foráneas.
Otra tabla con las mismas columnas, pero con 5 llaves primarias(PK).

Ambas tablas con 12 millones de registros. Haciendo pruebas con diferentes consultas: Select * from ... where campo1=$1 and campo2=$2 and campo3=$3 and campo4=$4 hay una diferencia en el tiempo de repuesta. La tabla con PK es 5 veces más rápida que las tablas sin PK, y no me explico por qué, gracias de antemano.
Estoy usando Postgresql 8.3

Comment: La magia de los indices de las claves primarias ;)

Comment: las consultas no las hago por los índices, sino con otros campos de la tabla

Comment: ¿La PK es alguna de las columnas de tu consulta?

Comment: Sí, Patricio Moracho

Comment: @Cesarvv no tiene sentido lo que dices. Si la PK esta en tu query ya estas usando su indice.

Comment: Ya voy entendiendo, entonces esa es la razón :o

Comment: Efectivamente, si uno de los filtros está indizado, una PK es un índice, el motor lo empleará sin dudas, para optimizar la consulta.

Comment: Dudo mucho que haya 5 PK, a menos que tu PK sea una llave compuesta de 5 columnas

Answer (score 0):

Pues si , las bases de datos relacionales tiene la peculiaridad de usar claves primarias y foráneas como indices para ubicar mas rápido los registros , imagina un diccionario   sus indices son números y cuando vas a buscar algo te guías por el indice del libro esto es mucho mas rápido que buscar palabras dentro de cada pagina. tampoco soy ningún experto en el tema pero algo se, espero te sirva de algo mi respuesta. (Y)

Comment: La creación de una clave foránea no implica crear un índice sobre el campo.

Comment: Cierto, pero en esta respuesta no dice explícitamente que añadir una FK cree un índice en la tabla que lleva el constraint. Es ambigua pero no estrictamente errónea